# How can I show a vertical white border in my footer?

Tags: html, css

I need to make a vertical white border in my footer at around 90% of the width.

This is what it should look like:

[image]

I currently have the same as in the image but without the white line on the right.

```css
footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #CDDE47;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <h2>Contact us</h2>
  <p><em>You can find our physical location on:<br>
                42 Tree lane, CB2345, Cambridge, Cambridgeshire, United Kingdom</em>
  </p>

  <a href=""><em>+44 (2345) 345 456</em></a>
  <br>
  <a href=""><em>info@growiteatit.co.uk</em></a>

  <ul>
    <li><a href=""><em>Check out our facebook page</em></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""><em>Check out our twitter feed</em></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved quite easily using the `:after` pseudoelement, which won't require you to modify your markup. Give the footer `position:relative`, then use CSS to place an absolutely-positioned bar inside it:

```css
footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #CDDE47;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
footer:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 10px;
  right: 50px;
  background: white;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <h2>Contact us</h2>
  <p><em>You can find our physical location on:<br>
            42 Tree lane, CB2345, Cambridge, Cambridgeshire, United Kingdom</em>
  </p>

  <a href=""><em>+44 (2345) 345 456</em></a>
  <br>
  <a href=""><em>info@growiteatit.co.uk</em></a>

  <ul>
    <li><a href=""><em>Check out our facebook page</em></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""><em>Check out our twitter feed</em></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 3):

Give your footer `position: relative` and add a div.verticalLine inside of it defined as so:

```
.verticalLine{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 10%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #CDDE47;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;             /* 1 */
}

footer::after {
  content: "";                    /* 2 */
  position: absolute;             
  width: 25px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  top: 0;
  right: 10%;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <h2>Contact us</h2>
  <p><em>You can find our physical location on:<br>
      42 Tree lane, CB2345, Cambridge, Cambridgeshire, United Kingdom</em>
  </p>
  <a href=""><em>+44 (2345) 345 456</em></a>
  <br>
  <a href=""><em>info@growiteatit.co.uk</em></a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href=""><em>Check out our facebook page</em></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""><em>Check out our twitter feed</em></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Notes:

1. Establish [nearest positioned ancestor for absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning).
2. Use an absolutely-positioned pseudo-element to create the border.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a pseudo element with CSS

```
footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #CDDE47;
  padding: 10px;
  position:relative;
}
footer:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    right:10%;
    width:10px;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

---

***Full demo***

```css
footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #CDDE47;
  padding: 10px;
  position:relative;
}
footer:after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  right:10%;
  width:10px;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <h2>Contact us</h2>
  <p><em>You can find our physical location on:<br>
                42 Tree lane, CB2345, Cambridge, Cambridgeshire, United Kingdom</em>
  </p>

  <a href=""><em>+44 (2345) 345 456</em></a>
  <br>
  <a href=""><em>info@growiteatit.co.uk</em></a>

  <ul>
    <li><a href=""><em>Check out our facebook page</em></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""><em>Check out our twitter feed</em></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

add one div into footer

```css
footer {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #CDDE47;
 }

.a1 {
    width: 90%;
    border-right: 10px solid #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="a1">
        <h2>Contact us</h2>
        <p><em>You can find our physical location on:<br>
            42 Tree lane, CB2345, Cambridge, Cambridgeshire, United Kingdom</em></p>

        <a href=""><em>+44 (2345) 345 456</em></a><br>
        <a href=""><em>info@growiteatit.co.uk</em></a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href=""><em>Check out our facebook page</em></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><em>Check out our twitter feed</em></a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an inner wrapper and apply the border & padding to that.

```css
footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #CDDE47;
}

.borderWrapper{
  border-right: solid 8px #fff;
  width: 90%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
<div class="borderWrapper">
  <h2>Contact us</h2>
  <p><em>You can find our physical location on:<br>
                42 Tree lane, CB2345, Cambridge, Cambridgeshire, United Kingdom</em>
  </p>

  <a href=""><em>+44 (2345) 345 456</em></a>
  <br>
  <a href=""><em>info@growiteatit.co.uk</em></a>

  <ul>
    <li><a href=""><em>Check out our facebook page</em></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""><em>Check out our twitter feed</em></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe use an :after pseudo element to create the white divider, and ensure the footer has position:relatve to contain the absolute element? e.g.

```
footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #CDDE47;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

footer::after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 30px;
 background: white;
 right: calc(10% - 15px);
 top: 0;
 height: 100%;
}
```